# Trying to get an object out of json using aeson

Tags: haskell, aeson

I am trying to get a Config data record out of the following code:

```
data Connections = Connections { cfgProperty  :: !Object
                   , connectionName :: String
                   } deriving (Show, Generic)

data Config = Config {connections :: [Connections]} deriving (Show, Generic)

data Cfg = Cfg { config :: Config } deriving (Show, Generic)



instance FromJSON Cfg
instance FromJSON Config
instance FromJSON Connections
instance ToJSON Cfg
instance ToJSON Config
instance ToJSON Connections

jsonFile :: FilePath
jsonFile = "config/config.json"

getCfg :: IO B.ByteString
getCfg = B.readFile jsonFile


parseCfg = do
      j <- (A.eitherDecode <$> getCfg) :: IO (Either String Cfg)
      case j of
        Left err ->  liftIO $ putStrLn err
        Right j -> config j
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
/apps/workspace/hade/src/Actor/MasterActor.hs: 56, 20
• Couldn't match expected type ‘IO ()’ with actual type ‘Config’
• In the expression: config j
  In a case alternative: Right j -> config j
  In a stmt of a 'do' block:
    case j of {
      Left err -> liftIO $ putStrLn err
      Right j -> config j }
```

Here is config.json

```
{
  "config":
  {
    "connections": [
    {
      "cfgProperty":
      {
        "Env": "local",
        "Host": "localhost",
        "Port": "8001",
        "Directory": "/apps/workspace/hade/maps/src01_cvs"
      },
      "connectionName": "src01_cvs"
    },
    {
        "cfgProperty":
        {
          "Env": "local",
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": "8001",
          "Directory": "/apps/workspace/hade/maps/trg01_cvs"
        },
        "connectionName": "trg01_cvs"
      }
    ]
  }
}{
  "config":
  {
    "connections": [
    {
      "cfgProperty":
      {
        "Env": "local",
        "Host": "localhost",
        "Port": "8001",
        "Directory": "/apps/workspace/hade/maps/src01_cvs"
      },
      "connectionName": "src01_cvs"
    },
    {
        "cfgProperty":
        {
          "Env": "local",
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": "8001",
          "Directory": "/apps/workspace/hade/maps/trg01_cvs"
        },
        "connectionName": "trg01_cvs"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have tried many different configurations using both eitherDecode and decode, but I have run into roadblocks each time.  I can get the code to print out the Config record if I change the case to be:

```
      case j of
        Left err ->  putStrLn err
        Right j -> print $ config j
```

(along with some other changes), but I cannot get it to simply return the Config record itself. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Here’s a hint: every branch of a `case` statement must return the same type. Additionally, the a `do` block has the same type as its last expression. What should the type of `parseCfg` be? If you put type annotations on all your top-level declarations (which you should do, anyway), the solution to your problem should become much clearer.

Comment: Does return $ config j work?

Comment: Alexis,  I'd be OK with returning an empty Config record from "Left ->" in order to make the types the same, but I'm not sure how I would do that. Any ideas?  I've tried a few different things, but with no success to this point.

Comment: Someone put a great deal of effort into an answer and then for some reason it disappeared.  Just curious what happened?

Comment: I answered the question and then deleted my answer because, after giving it some thought, I didn't like it.  I'm going to post an improvement but I didn't want to take a chance that the previous one would be accepted in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of the problem that you are running into is the call to `getCfg` in `parseCfg`.  The type of `getCfg` is `IO ByteString` which is an `IO` monad and the only things that you can do with an `IO` monad are to call the functions that must be defined for all monads (`bind`, `fmap`, `ap`, ...) all of which return another `IO` monad.  This means that if `parseCfg` is going to call `getCfg` then it *must* return an `IO` monad.

To quote the [haskell wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/All_About_Monads#No_way_out) : "Because you can't escape from the IO monad, it is impossible to write a function that does a computation in the IO monad but whose result type does not include the `IO` type constructor."

One way around this is to call `getCfg` outside of `parseCfg` and pass the result to `parseCfg`.  Then `parseCfg` *could* return a `Config` but it makes more sense to return `Either String Config` so that any parsing error from `eitherDecode` is preserved.  This lets you define `parseCfg` as nothing more than an `fmap` of `config` over the `eitherDecode` return value.

The resulting function looks like this:

```
parseCfg :: ByteString -> Either String Config
parseCfg json = config <$> eitherDecode json
```

Here is your program, modified to run with the above `parseCfg`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Data.ByteString.Lazy as B
import Data.Aeson 
import Data.Aeson.TH
import GHC.Generics
import Control.Monad.IO.Class

data CfgProperty = CfgProperty { 
                       env             :: String,
                       host            :: String,
                       port            :: String,
                       directory       :: String
                   } deriving (Show, Generic)

-- Instead of FromJSON, use deriveJSON for CfgProperty 
-- which allows changing of field labels from lower 
-- case to upper case.

$(deriveJSON 

      defaultOptions { fieldLabelModifier = let f "env" = "Env"
                                                f "host" = "Host"
                                                f "port" = "Port"
                                                f "directory" = "Directory"
                                                f other = other
                                             in f
                     } 

      ''CfgProperty
 )

data Connections = Connections { cfgProperty  :: CfgProperty
                   , connectionName :: String
                   } deriving (Show, Generic)

data Config = Config {connections :: [Connections]} deriving (Show, Generic)

data Cfg = Cfg { config :: Config } deriving (Show, Generic)

instance FromJSON Cfg
instance FromJSON Config
instance FromJSON Connections

jsonFile :: FilePath
jsonFile = "config/config.json"

getCfg :: IO ByteString
getCfg = B.readFile jsonFile

parseCfg :: ByteString -> Either String Config
parseCfg json = config <$> eitherDecode json 

main :: IO()
main = do
    json <- getCfg
    case parseCfg json of
        Left err ->  Prelude.putStrLn err
        Right cfg -> print cfg  -- do whatever you want with cfg here.
```

Here's a modified `config.json`.  The original contained two `config` `JSON` records with nothing between them which was not valid `JSON`, and was not pertinent to the question.

```
{
  "config":
  {
    "connections": [
    {
      "cfgProperty":
      {
        "Env": "local",
        "Host": "localhost",
        "Port": "8001",
        "Directory": "/apps/workspace/hade/maps/src01_cvs"
      },
      "connectionName": "src01_cvs"
    },
    {
        "cfgProperty":
        {
          "Env": "local",
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": "8001",
          "Directory": "/apps/workspace/hade/maps/trg01_cvs"
        },
        "connectionName": "trg01_cvs"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```